# Create Thymeleaf WebContext in ServiceLayer

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've got a Spring Boot 2  Webapp which generate a downloadable PDF. For this, I've got a `PDFDownloadController` which calls my `PDFService`. This service is generating my PDF. Therefore, it passes a `org.thymeleaf.Context` to the Thymeleaf `TemplateEngine`.

At first, this context was enough to fulfill my requirements. Now, I want to use

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('USER')">
```

in my html-template. However, this feature needs a WebContext.

So I started to create a `WebContext` in my `PDFService` and pass it to the `TemplateEngine`. The problem now is, that this `WebContext` needs some additional parameters (`HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ServletContext context`). To access them in my servicelayer i pass those parameters from my controller to my service as method arguments. And the `sec:authorize` works!

However, I know this is not a good design. How should i pass those parameters to my servicelayer? Or do i need another design?

Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Don't. Let the controller generate the PDF not the service.

Comment: Isn't it the job of a service to do this? Maybe it's not the only controller which want to generate a PDF. Therefore I think it is better  to perform the generation in its own service.

Comment: The PDF is a representation of a model and you are using web technology to create  a PDF. So either stop using web based technologies to generate the PDF or move it to the correct layer. Don't let the web related things leak into your service layer.